# Caution Issue in Action_open_Document_Tree

Tags: java, android

I am get the Sdcard data(media,video,Images) through Action_Open_Document_Tree method in that they mention one Caution issue.

Caution issue: If you iterate through a large number of files within the directory that's accessed using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, your app's performance might be reduced.

But I need to read Large number of media files in sdcard.

sdcard is a removable storage(micro sdcard) , The above mention caution is mentioned  in Android developer website, I need clarification of this caution issue. I tried with media store in that i can't able to get media content from removable storage, so only I moved with Action_open_document_tree method

so i confused because of this issue it is any thing serious of this caution issue,or any other alternative method is there.

Comment: What do you mean with Sdcard? I asked that before. Why are you still writing Action_open_Document_Tree where you have been asked not to do so? What do you learn of comments you get?

Comment: sdcard is a removable storage(micro sdcard) , I see this caution in Android developer website, I need clarification of this caution issue. I tried with media store in that i can't able to get media content from removable storage, so only I moved with Action_open_document_tree method

Comment: I see. You learned nothing.

Comment: What is your problem? It is just a caution, i.e. a warning. That doesn't it wouldn't work. You can still do it, just keep that in mind when you are feeling lack in performance this may be the cause.

Comment: @RickyMo No problem just I am asking of this caution issue because I am going  to release one music app in that i need sdcard media content so, I get the removable(sdcard) media content from Action_open_Document_tree method , but se this caution issue in future if any problem came or not of this caution issue